# How to show configurable product stock status in magento?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento-1, quantity, stock-status

I want to show the stock status of child product when the configurable option is selected in the frontend.

For example product C1 has S1 ( 1 qty ) and S2 (10 qty ) children. "Only X left Threshold" is set to 5. So when user selects S1 option, it has to show the message "only 1 left", if S2 option is selected then no need to show message as its qty is more than the threshold set.

Comment: Please  tell me where are you want to  show it.Just give a screen shot

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit the question to show what you have tried and what your exact problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_product` is your `configurable product`.

To get all its simple use :

```
$_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product);
```

So you might have something like :

```
foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product) as $simple) {
     $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();
     echo $simple->getName()." with size ".$simple->getSize()." have a stock of $stock";
     echo '<br/>';
 }
```

**For M2**

```
$_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product);
```

So you might have something like :

```
foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product) as $simple) {
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
     $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStat‌​eInterface');
     echo $simple->getName()." with size ".$simple->getSize()." have a stock of " . $StockState->getStockQty($simple->getId(), $simple->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
     echo '<br/>';
 }
```

Comment: Do you have a code for Magento 2 also?

Comment: @Anitr did not try this code in M2 try it mostly the code are same

Comment: This is the right code for M2: 
`$_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
        foreach ($_children as $child){
            echo $child->getName();
            echo 'stock: ' . $StockState->getStockQty($child->getId(), $child->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        }`

Comment: this will not work `$StockState->getStockQty($child->getId(), $child->getStore()->getWebsiteId());` you have to get it from stock model M2 way

Comment: Sorry, also this comes before: `$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');` And it works - it shows the correct stock quantity.

Comment: @Anitr glad it worked :) i updated the code for future reader too.. find any error feel free to edit..

Comment: In Magento 2 you can simply use `$configurableProduct->isAvailable()` to check if any of its children are in stock. If all children are out of stock, `isAvailable()` will return 0 (and no "Add to Cart button will be rendered") and if any child Simple Product is in stock, it will return 1.